# Python return occurrence of n lists recursively without slicing / deepcopy or inbuilt functions

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

You cannot use inbuilt functions or slicing or deepcopy or copy, or while or for

Lets say this is our function:

```
def list_occur(n):
```

it takes n as int parameter input and returns a list with size n that shows the element n in this series ( output ):

```
n = 0: returns []
n = 1: returns list with size 1 that takes in index=0 [], means returns [ [] ]
n = 2: returns list with size 2 that takes in index=0 [] and index = 1 [ [] ], means returns:
[ [], [ [] ] ]
n = 3: returns list with size 3 that takes in index=0 [], index =1 [ [] ], index = 2 [ [], [ [] ] ] 
means its returns [ [], [ [] ], [ [], [ [] ] ] ]
```

my try to solve this problem, but i get error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' when i try n = 2 + :

```
  def occur(n) :

    return occr_helper(n)



def occr_helper(n) :

    if (n == 0):
        return []

    return occr_helper(n-1).append(occr_helper(n-1))

    if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(occur(1))
```

Comment: `empty_list.append([])` returns None. You're passing None into your recursive call.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, i will try to solve the problem again as it seems wrong, any direction? @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this function `n+1` returns `n` appended to `n`. This can easily be coded recursively:

```
num = 3

def occr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        new_l = occr(n-1)
        new_l.append(occr(n-1))
        return new_l

print(occr(num))
```

Comment: Your method working fine, I edited my code again but Im still having the error of None Type, can you clarify why yours working and for me not?

Comment: @SchevenzRs the `list.append` function will always return `None`. That's why instead of having one line saying `return new_l.append(occr(n-1))` I needed to have two lines: `new_l.append(occr(n-1))` and `return new_l`.

Comment: Great observation that `n+1` is `n` appended to `n`! However you would improve speed greatly by replacing your `else` block with `new_l = occr(n-1);  return new_l + [new_l]`